# Is Dr nic's magic models plugin/gem works with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, compatibility

Is D[r Nic's Magic Model](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/) plugin/gem working with rails 3??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge (disclaimer: I used to work with him), it is unmaintained and therefore probably doesn't work with Rails 3.